# My Character’s Armature keeps flying off the screen

Tags: game-engine, armature, physics

I have made a character on blender using the blender game engine. The character is rigged and weight painted properly.

[image]

However, when I set the armature to physics: character, and press p, the whole mesh and armature flies off the screen into the distance.

Is there anyway to fix this or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably happening because your character has a static physics type..

Just select the character (mesh) and set its physics to "No Collision"

[image]

A better setup would be as follow :

- Main character mesh - Physics : **No Collision**.
- Armature - Physics : **No Collision**.
- Add a mesh representing the character collision box - Physics : **Character** or whatever you like!
- Parent the *armature* to the *collision* box and that's it!

*The armature would control the animations (actions) and the collision box would control everything else*

[image]

Comment: Hi there. Sorry it has been a while since I replied! But how do I create a collision box? Do I add a lattice or an empty? I tried using a lattice - scaling up to match my character and then parenting my armature to it - but when I tested it in play, it just disappeared! Is it a different way?